# Grails - HQL Exception when comparing date field to today

Tags: grails, hql, grails-2.0

I have the following HQL query that I'm running against an H2 database:

```
"select count(*) from Event as e where " +
   "e.org.id = :orgId and " +
   "e.deleted = :deleted and " +
   "e.startDate >= :startDate and " +
   "lower(e.name) like :name " +
   "order by startDate asc"
```

It works fine for all startDate params except those that are today. If the startDate is today, I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: 

could not execute query; uncategorized SQLException for SQL 
[select count(*) as col_0_0_ from event event0_ where event0_.org_id=? and 
event0_.deleted=? and event0_.start_date>=? and 
(lower(event0_.event_name) like ?) order by event0_.start_date asc]; 

SQL state [90016]; error code [90016]; 
Column "EVENT0_.START_DATE" must be in the GROUP BY list; SQL statement:
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: what about startDate in the future?

Comment: startDate in the past or future works fine.

Comment: Did you mean `order by e.startDate asc`?

Comment: Yes, it should be `order by e.startDate asc`but that didn't solve the problem. I actually don't need the ordering since it's a count query so I got rid of it and the problem went away.